# Meaning of 掃き溜める

Tags: meaning, usage, verbs, nouns

Context: a boxer is telling another one that he is too weak to participate in a tournament.

> 潰し合いさせられるトーナメントに浮かれてんの出場者ん中でお前だけだぞ？**掃き溜められた**コトにムカつくけどよ…　お前みてェな甘ちゃんと肩並ばされんのはもっとハラが立つ。

Looking in the dictionary, I could find 掃き溜め only as a noun, not as a verb. Is it an uncommon use? And what is its meaning here? Considering the context, I think it could mean something like "I hate I was put in the same tournament with such weak boxers...". Is my translation correct? You can see the [whole page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0VFW.jpg). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely a transformation of the word. 掃き溜め is defined as a garbage dump, but in this case turned into a verb (Remember Google? ググる is "to Google something"). This is where you add your own contextual understanding of the sentence.

It seemed that the speaker is pissed off at being treated like trash, "binned" or "boxed" together with other... in his words, garbage-quality athletes.